# I'm having issues tuning my classical guitar

Tags: guitar, tuning, classical-guitar

For some reason I cannot tune my classical guitar, I've used phone apps and actual tuners.
I'm starting to believe that the issue is that the guitar is too cheapy. I bought for 100$ from  the brand fender. I'm especially having problems with my low E string, it sounds terrible. I replaced the string and it still sounds the same, it has this very high pitched sound. I've tried to make it lower pitch and it sounds even worse.
I'm not sure what to do at this point. All the strings sound so plastic like instead of a more savory sound a classical guitar is supposed to have.
I'm not sure what the brand of the strings are originally when I bought it but I bought and used DAddrío pro larté nylon core normal intention classical guitar strings if that helps anyone.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a tuning issue.  Could you share an audio recording?

Comment: Yeah the tone is different from the tuning. A photo of the guitar and the strings might help also. And how are you trying to tune? With an electronic tuner?

Comment: I've tried turning by ear, I've tried it with electronic tuner and phone apps

Comment: You really have to separate the tone from the tuning. The tuning comes from the tension of the strings. The tone comes from your right hand technique.

Comment: Has it always been like this? If possible, return it to the shop, and let them solve the problem.

Comment: @ToddWilcox of course there are mechanical factors independent of the player's technique that also affect the tone.   Most of these have nothing to do with tuning either, of course.

Comment: Welcome! To make the question answerable, please use the "Edit" button to add some more information. Right now this question seems to be about tone—the way a string might "sound different" even if it's in tune, might have a richer or thinner sound. If you're having trouble even making it be an E, then please tell more about the trouble you're having—is the string changing pitch on its own? Are you having trouble telling whether it needs to move up or down?

Comment: As you say, it could be the quality of the instrument if it's cheaper.  I have a cheap one that is impossible to play in tune.  I gave up and bought a nicer one.  You could take yours to a reputable repairer and see if they can do anything.

Comment: I would take it to a shop and ask someone there for an opinion.  You might need to make an appointment.  I don't know what this type of appointment is called.  For string instruments, one makes an appointment for an adjustment.

Comment: A video or audio clip of how it actually sounds would be really helpful. Some time ago I bought an acoustic guitar and tried some Fenders at the time. They did not sound or feel great but the ones on display weren't so bad that they couldn't be played in tune so I suspect it's something else.

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure though how to add a video or audio clip. I you could tell me how do that I would be happy to add that. Thank you.

Comment: @Mya You can upload a clip to Youtube, Soundcloud, or another website, and then post a link to it here.

Comment: “I've tried it with electronic tuner and phone apps” — and what do those tell you? Is the pitch always too high, no matter how much you loosen the string; or too low, no matter how much you tighten it? Does it alternative between being too high and too low, and you can't find (or stay on) the right tension? Does tuning one string cause others to go out of tune? Does the tuner not show a pitch for the string(s) in question? Or does it show the correct pitch but you don't like the sound?

Answer (score 1):

It could be a problem of distances between the Nut and the Bridge, or maybe the tuning peg does not allow you to be as exact with the turns. However, if this problem is increased by playing a note somewhere on the fret, you could add a neck bend problem. Cheap guitars are usually a mess with tuning.

Comment: How does poor intonation give high pitched sound on low E string?